# Yii booster navbar ajaxLink

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Is it possible to make Yii booster navbar use ajaxLinks instead of simple links?
Browsing through the extension code didn't give me any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use directly jquery ajax function for this, just give a menu id or class name then use this for ajax link